# How to runlong running tasks in iOS which are dependent on each other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, queue

I want to run some tasks which are dependent on each other so should be performed in an order. Currently, it blocks my UI thread and also there is some issue in ordering.

Couple of questions regarding this:

- Tasks are not performed in correct order. What change to be made if we want them to be performed one after other
- Is the code optimised in terms of memory usage and resource consumption? How it can be made more optimised?
- Do we need global queues inside function call also as shown in code below?

Here are my code details. I have created some serial queues as follows:

```
var Q0_sendDisplayName=dispatch_queue_create("Q0_sendDisplayName",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
var Q1_fetchFromDevice=dispatch_queue_create("fetchFromDevice",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
var Q2_sendPhonesToServer=dispatch_queue_create("sendPhonesToServer",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

I have an idea that serial queues perform tasks in order so i have called my tasks on serial queues. Here is my code:

```
  dispatch_sync(Q0_sendDisplayName,
        {
            self.sendNameToServer(displayName){ (result) -> () in

                dispatch_sync(self.Q1_fetchFromDevice,
                    {
                         self.SyncfetchContacts({ (result) -> () in


                            dispatch_sync(self.Q2_sendPhonesToServer,
                                {       self.SyncSendPhoneNumbersToServer(self.syncPhonesList, completion: { (result) in



                                                //.......
                                                //....
```

The code inside these functions is also running on global queue. Dont know if it is a correct way to code. I have used completion handlers to notify that method has completed executing. Here is the code of function1:

```
  func sendNameToServer(var displayName:String,completion:(result:Bool)->())
  {
   Alamofire.request(.POST,"\(urlToSendDisplayName)",headers:header,parameters:["display_name":displayName]).responseJSON{
            response in
            switch response.result {
                 case .Success:
                   return completion(result: true) //......
```

Here is the code of function2. This function is long as it reads whole contacts book so i have placed it inside global queue(dont know if it is right way). I call completion handler on main queue. Here is code:

```
func SyncfetchContacts(completion:(result:Bool)->())
{
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()

    var keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataKey]
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)){

    do {

         try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)) { (contact, pointer) -> Void in
            if (contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey)) {
                for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                    let a = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber

        }
        }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            completion(result: true)
        }
        }
 //........
```

Here is the code for function3 which again inside has a global queue(dont know if its right) and calls completion handler on main queue.

```
func SyncSendPhoneNumbersToServer(phones:[String],completion: (result:Bool)->()){
   Alamofire.request(.POST,"\(url)",headers:header,parameters:["display_name":displayName]).responseJSON{
        response in
        switch response.result {
             case .Success:
                       dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0))
            {
              //enter some large data in database in a loop
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
               {
               return completion(result: true)
               }


             }//......
```

Comment: Since the tasks all have completion blocks, there is no need for the dispatch_sync calls. You can use a dispatch group if you want to perform some final action once all of the work is done.

Comment: Thanks. do we need `dispatch_sync` inside functions still?

Answer (score 0):

In `SyncfetchContacts` you are calling the completion handler before `contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest` has finished, outside of its completion closure.

Simply move it in there:

```
func SyncfetchContacts(completion:(result:Bool)->()) {

    ...

    do {

        try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)) { (contact, pointer) -> Void in
            if (contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey)) {
                for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                    let a = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber

                }
            }
            // here ...
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completion(result: true)
            }
        }
// ... not here.
//            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
//                completion(result: true)
//            }
    }
}
```